# Meus dados não vão para o BD usando ionic e php

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo uma app em Ionic.
Na hora de salvar, a seguinte mensagem aparece no console:

> http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/vcApp/www/php/salvaEndereco.php 500 (Internal Server Error) ionic.bundle.js:19346 POST

Seguem meus códigos

controller do angular:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('enderecoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.adicionarEndereco = function (endereco){
        $http.post("php/salvaEndereco.php", endereco).success(function (data){

        });
    }
})
```

php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');

include_once("con.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$cep = $request['cep'];
$uf = $request['uf'];
$cidade = $request['cidade'];
$bairro = $request['bairro'];
$logradouro = $request['logradouro'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO cep VALUES(NULL, '$cep', '$uf', '$cidade', '$bairro', '$logradouro')";

mysqli_query($con, $insert);
?>
```

Comment: Consegui
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');
include_once("con.php");
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);
$cep  = $data->cep;
$uf  = $data->uf;
$cidade  = $data->cidade;
$bairro  = $data->bairro;
$logradouro  = $data->logradouro;
$insert = "INSERT INTO cep VALUES(NULL, '$cep', '$uf', '$cidade', '$bairro', '$logradouro')";
mysqli_query($con, $insert);